# Is it on topic to ask how to act with clients?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I've read through the meta and the (tiny) [faq page for on-topic questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

But nothing specifically states "You can('t) ask about what to do/how to act with a client".

I'm thinking about asking a question (with a bit of humor), but it is really focused on how to act with a client.

But I don't want my question closed in 2m with 5 downvotes.

I don't want to waste everybody's time.

Said this, is it on topic to ask how to act with clients?

Comment: FWIW, [asking for advice on what to do](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695/168) is explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic]

Comment: @gnat Is the way I aproach a client or what I do while talking to him/her off-topic?

Comment: did you check [meta guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695/168) referred in prior comment?

Comment: @gnat That's talking about advice...

Comment: @gnat at some level, *all* questions on Stack Exchange are "what to do" -- you have a problem and you want to solve it, after all.  Our restriction on "what to do" questions is more focused -- questions that describe a situation and ask "so what do I do?" without identifying something more specific (all Ann Landers style).  *That's* what we object to here, not questions with clear problems that can be addressed through the SE Q&A process.  Ismael's question is whether those questions may include the topic of client interactions, and I'm glad he brought the question here.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thank you a lot! Can you please add that information to the question? I'm really having a few troubles to express myself (I guess it is obvious, since you had to clarify it).

Comment: @MonicaCellio agree - I only pointed to our custom close reason to remind that _some_ kinds of "what to do" questions are off-topic

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I think your question is clear as-is.  My difference is with gnat, not you -- you're fine!

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thanks miss. I guess no one else saw the big issue here, since I have 0 freaking answers. It is the goddamn 1st question on the "newest" tab. And look: 0 answers. I must say that I'm pretty disapointed.

Comment: you are probably comparing Workplace meta against CG.SE / CR.SE / SO. Per my observations, at smaller site metas questions, especially non-obvious ones, tend to be simply answered much slower. One has to just get used to that

Comment: @gnat I have no idea what sites are those...

Comment: you have [accounts on all of them](http://stackexchange.com/users/3235633/ismael-miguel?tab=accounts). CG stands for Code Golf, CR for Code Review, SO for Stack Overflow

Comment: @gnat CG should be PPCG. That's why I didn't had any idea of what you meant. But yes, I do. And usually the number of views is directly related to the number of answers. I've had answers to questions with 5 views! At the time of writting of this comment, this question had 48 views. And a lot of comments. But no answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have a [clients](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clients) tag with over 200 questions, and also a [communication](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication) tag, so I'd say those questions are in-scope.  We can't help with the *technical details of your clients' work* (e.g. how do I build this web site that he wants?), but questions about negotiating work/payment/schedule, setting expectations, dealing with problems (like schedule slippages), and behavior norms (the valuable client has these problem behaviors) are all in-scope.

Sometimes questions get put on hold, but it's not because anybody wants to be mean.  Sometimes they just need a little editing or additional information -- what was clear to the asker didn't come through for the rest of us.  So don't take it personally if a question is put on hold; we would all prefer that questions be open and answered.  Sometimes we just need a little time-out to make sure the question is clear in in-scope, is all.

Comment: I've looked into the tags before asking, and I have no idea how I have't seen a `clients` tag. I tried `client`, `costumer` and similars.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I sometimes find our tag set a little confusing.  It happens.  (Searching for or starting to add "client" should have suggested "clients", though; if that didn't happen, please let us know.)

Comment: Probably it was my entire fault because (you know) I use IE (for reasons that sadden me). But this isn't the first time that I try to find a tag when asking a question and I don't find it. Or at least I don't remember. But you are really helpful. No wonder you are moderator.